# Inconsistent Line Text

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a test website and I'm on my contact page and I'm having a slight issue.  My line height is inconsistent, and is making some of my website look ugly.

```css
.address {
  margin-left: 23%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.phone {
  margin-left: 12%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.email {
  margin-left: 12%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="address">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-4x icons" style="color: #1BA166; margin-left: 25%;" aria-hidden="true"></i> Lawyer Building 123 Fake Street Pluto, Mars, 60210 Galaxy
</div>
<div class="phone">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x icons" style="color: #1BA166; margin-left: 25%;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p>1-555-555-5555</p>
</div>
<div class="email">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-4x icons" style="color: #1BA166; margin-left: 25%;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p>info@info.ca</p>
  <p>sales@info.ca</p>
  <p>careers@info.ca</p>
</div>
```

And here's a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: `p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` add this to css and it will be same.

Comment: You are wrapping one in `<p>` tags and the not the other, and your CSS does not modify the tags so they will have some default spacing. You might want to consider wrapping the address in a `<p>` as well, and then minimizing the padding and margin on the paragraph. Or consider a semantically more valid element, like and `<li>` for a list of phone numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you wrap the email addresses in an own `p` tag.

You could add

```
p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

to your CSS file.

Comment: Maybe consider using something like `<address>` instead?